# Contar recorrentes

Tags: powerbi, dax

Boa tarde!
Eu tenho uma tabela de vendas com dois anos sendo 2020 e 2021, eu preciso fazer os seguintes cálculos:

valor das vendas do produto em 2021 * quantidade de vendas do produto 2021
valor das vendas do produto em 2020 * quantidade de vendas do produto 2021
***a quantidade das vendas sempre será 2021***.
O problema é que eu só posso considerar produtos estiveram nos dois anos, produtos que passaram em apenas um ano não podem ser incluídos no cálculo.

Estou anexando uma imagem + passo a passo de como fiz no Excel.

1 ° Passo
Valor de venda do produto em 2020 * Número de produtos vendidos - 2021

2 ° Passo
valor de venda do produto em 2021 * Número de produtos vendidos - 2021

3 ° Some o total de produtos após a multiplicação(Somar o total do 1° e 2° passo de forma separada)

4 °
Divida a soma de 2021 pela soma de 2020 - 1 ( A/B-1 )

O valor de que preciso é aquele em amarelo:( na imagem)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Um maneira seria utilizar o `SUMX()`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra maneira seria utilizar o `SELECTEDVALUE()`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]